# magento-how to refund only Partial amount while creating memo

Tags: php, magento

I have a site ware i have to refund Partial amount of the order to the customer. For example if the product price is 1000 and it's weight is 100gm. But after manufacturing The weight of the product is not exactly the same. So after complete the order i have to return some amount to the customer based on the final weight of the final product. how to do it?

Comment: i think u can achieve this with default magento functionality. by setting adjustment amounts of creditmemo. Magento gives 2 types Adjustment Refund and adjustment fee.

Comment: In response to your deleted question about calculating gold price for different carat ratings: `purity = carat / 24` and `carat price = 24carat price * purity / 100`

Comment: in the below formula what is the need of 100 ? "carat price = 24carat price * purity / 100"